# Chrome Adobe Flash is out of date

Tags: google-chrome, flash

I keep getting this browser (chrome) notification saying

> Adobe Flash Player was blocked because it is out of date. **Update**,  **Run This Time**

If I click run this time it allows me to run any flash content on current page but same notification on new page. If however, I click update plugin it takes me to [this Chrome support page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6258784). I follow instructions and go to chrome://plugins which give me a url under Adobe Flash Player which is following  [Download Critical Security Update](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6258784) and as you see this again links me to the Google support page with instructions on how to update and that I've already been on.

Comment: I haven't seen that notification for a long time. What O.S you got installed? What version of Chrome? If you can see NPAPI version listed in your `chrome://plugins` then disable it & use only PPAPI version (that one has auto-update anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same issue with Chrome on my `Linux` system.

Here is my solution for **Linux** system:

- Install chrome 55+, if you have an older version.
- Download flash player,
  url:    http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/
- step 1 - os
  choose "*linux 64 bit*",
- step 2 - version
  choose "*FP xx for linux 64-bit (.tar.gz) - PPAPI*",
- Download,
- Uncompress,
- Copy files in the directory into `~/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash/`,
- Make it executable via: `chmod +x libpepflashplayer.so`
- Append parameter to chrome's start command,

  Where is the command:
  (1) for icon,
      right click icon -> properties, there is "command" input,
  (2) for shortcut,
      config the shortcut,

  The parameter to append is:
      `--ppapi-flash-path=/home/eric/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so`
  e.g.
    `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U --ppapi-flash-path=/home/eric/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so`
- Restart chrome,
- Now the flash should work.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have solved your issue by now, but for the benefit of others:  Flash is now provided as a so-called component and updated separately from the main Chrome application.  I would therefore suggest first checking chrome://components and manually check for an update there.

By the way, the same is true for the Widevine DRM component, which if not up-to-date may stop Netflix, etc. from running.